# How to update clearcase snapshot view with config_spec file

Tags: clearcase, snapshot-view

I created a snapshot view, which has folder structure as the following:

```
View_1
View_1.vws
```

.vws folder has a config_spec file. If I modify the config_spec file and from view shortcuts > right click > update view. The config spec from the file are not getting addressed. Only if I change the config spec from clearcase UI, (that is view properties > edit config_spec) then only the view gets updated.

I used to do this often. The difference in the setup where this is working, is only, it has view.stg folder which has config_spec file, instead of .vws folder.

Can somebody please suggest what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to edit the config spec, you should not edit the one from the view workspace (`.vws`)

Type instead [`cleartool edcs`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_edcs.htm) or [`cleartool setcs -curent`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm) (from any folder within `View_1`): that will achieve the same purpose, without using the GUI.

Comment: editing the config_spec file directly will have odd behaviors. This file is not guaranteed to be read by the view server unless you edit the configspec (cleartool edcs, etc.) or use cleartool setcs -current. Some versions would reread it on view server process startup, but that's not documented behavior and is subject to change w/o notice.

Comment: @BrianCowan I agree. And best wishes for this new year.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the inputs.

cleartool setcs -current

worked for me.

Comment: It is FAR better to use cleartool edcs or cleartool setcs {filename} than to edit the file in the view storage and issue a cleartool setcs -current. Your current mechanism depends on officially undocumented behavior that could change. You also open a window where the real and displayed configspecs don't line up, and this could lead to user confusion.